# GPU showing artifacts and failing to boot with GPU drivers installed

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I’ve been having problems with my GPU since last night. I was playing a game when suddenly the game froze, green and purple artifacts showed up and the game minimized to desktop before continuing after a minute or so. This happened maybe six times before I got a BSOD (with BCCode 116). Even though drivers should not have been an issue (I was playing Batman: Arkham Asylum) I decided to update them just in case. Everything seemed well and I went downstairs to grab myself a drink but when I got back I found my PC stuck in a bootloop. A few seconds after the Windows logo there would be a brief pattern of distorted lines before the screen went black and the system restarted.

[Video](https://vid.me/hTi4)

[image]

So far I’ve tried a few things:

- I’ve booted my PC into safe mode and cleaned my GPU drivers using Display Driver Uninstaller. The display was fine in safe mode and after I’ve rebooted. (so without any drivers enabled) After rebooting Windows automatically reinstalled the latest driver. This didn’t help and I was having the same issues as before so I decided to clean my GPU drivers again and reinstalled the drivers I was using before all this, but the same thing kept happening.
- Secondly I’ve tried cleaning and reslotting the card, but that didn’t make any difference.
- I’ve also tried connecting my display using the second DVI port just in case but that didn’t make any difference either.

I also got a disk read error once, but I couldn’t replicate it so it might have been a coincidence.

Mobo: Asrock 890FX Deluxe3
CPU: AMD Phenom II x6 1090T
GPU: NVIDIA GTX 570 (Gainward model)
OS: Windows 7

TL;DR: Can boot into Windows without GPU drivers just fine, stuck in a bootloop with them installed.

Has anyone seen anything similar? I just hope I haven’t fried my card just yet.

Comment: Based on what you described.  I am certain the card needs to be replaced.  A display artifact is a symptom of a hardware problem not software. As for the reason it "works" without the drivers, well the drivers allow the hardware to be fully utlized, it working without the drives is typical in a case like this.

Comment: That's what I figured, I was just hoping I missed something obvious.